# How can I add single quotes to a variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have this:
`$animal=cat;`
how can I add single quotes to this variable to get an output of, for example, 'cat'?

```
echo "$animal";

//Output 'cat'
```

Comment: ... `echo "'$animal'";` ?

Comment: Variables aren't interpreted in single-quoted strings. Use double quotes, like in the code you've shared.

Comment: $animal = "'cat'"; will display with siingle quotes. echo $animal;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
echo "\"$animal\"";
```

Or you can just use single quotes instead as the following:

```
echo '"$animal"';
```

Whichever you prefer.

Comment: `echo '"$animal"';` will output `"$animal"`.

Comment: @Federkun, yeah thank you I messed up between single quotes and double quotes.

Comment: @user9154057 If this helped you, then your question is wrong. The first example will output double quotes around the value and the second will output `"$animal"`. There's no single quotes here (which is what you said you wanted).

Comment: @user9154057 Please if that is what you want then you have to change your question, otherwise, tell me so I can delete my answer.

Comment: @andrewnagyeb nono perfect i used the first example :)

Comment: First example! Just what I needed. Ty

Answer (score 5):

```
echo "'$animal'";
```

Just write signle quotes before and after variable but remember variable should be written in double quotes

Answer (score 2):

simply like this

```
echo "'". $animal. "'";
// output 'cat'
```